# How to unify 2 objects into a coherent facade?

Tags: c#

I am using 2 classes from a 3rd party library, lets call them Obj1 and Obj2.  They have a nearly identical set properties and methods, save a few.  Both are standalone objects and do not inherit from anything common.

The problem is that in my code I have to have 2 path for both of these objects, even though the work I do on them is identical.  Example:

```
void Foo1(Obj1 obj) {
     obj.Cost = calcCostObj1(obj);
     obj.Rate = generateRateObj1(obj);
     ... // 50 more lines of this
}

void Foo2(Obj2 obj) {
     obj.Cost = calcCostObj2(obj);
     obj.Rate = generateRateObj2(obj);
     ...
}
```

Sure, I can overload the methods, but it's still 2 methods for pretty much every operation...

Unfortunately, I can't modify the 3rd party library. Is there a method (unlikely, i know) in C#, where I can somehow unify these 2 classes into a single interface so that I don't have to have 2 methods to deal with everything.

Or at least generisize the situation.

P.S.  My dream scenario (currently not possible with C#):

```
void Foo<T>(T obj) where T: Obj1, Obj2 {
    obj.Cost = calcCostObj<T>(obj);
    obj.Rate = calcRateObj<T>(obj);
}

// calling code
Obj1 obj = new Obj1();
Foo<Obj1>(obj);
```

Comment: What would your code sample look like it you got what you wanted?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Dream scenario updated.

Comment: Do you have access to `dynamic`?

Comment: If you don't need compile-time type checking, then you can create a generic `Foo<T>(dynamic obj)` method. It ensures `obj` is of type `T` at run-time. In a sense, you put the generics `where` inside the method.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin that should be no better than passing everything as `object`.  Since both of them have practically the same set of properties and methods.  I'd prefer strong typing.

Comment: The technique that I showed won't work with `object`, because to access the properties and methods, you would have to cast object as either `Obj1` or `Obj2`. That would result in the code duplication that you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to `dynamic`, you can do exactly your dream scenario:

```
var obj = new Obj1();
Foo<Obj1>(obj);
```

Here is a [running code sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/unCc24). It has a generic `Foo<T>(dynamic obj)` method that ensures `obj` is of type `T` at run-time. In a sense, you put the generic's `where` inside the method. You just don't get compile-time type checking.

## Running Code Example

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Foo<T>(dynamic obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is T)) 
        {
            var message = 
                string.Format("Expecting type of <{0}>.", typeof(T).Name);
            throw new System.ArgumentException(message);
        }
        obj.Cost = "11.99";
        obj.Rate = "0.50";

        // obj.Nope = ""; // RuntimeBinderException
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new Obj1();
        Foo<Obj1>(obj);
        System.Console.WriteLine("${0} at ${1}/hr.", obj.Cost, obj.Rate);

        // Foo<Obj1>(""); // ArgumentException
    }
}

public class Obj1
{
    public string Cost, Rate;
}

public class Obj2
{
    public string Cost, Rate;
}
```

### Also Constrain `T`

The above doesn't actually constrain `T` though, so if you needed also to constrain `T`, then you could use this:

```
public static void Bar<T>(dynamic obj)
{
    bool IsTypeRight = 
        (typeof(Obj1) == typeof(T) || typeof(Obj2) == typeof(T));
    bool IsObjRight = obj is T;
    if (!IsTypeRight || !IsObjRight)
    {
        var message = 
            string.Format("Expecting type of <{0}>.", typeof(T).Name);
        throw new System.ArgumentException(message);
    }
    // ...
}
```

### Edit: This technique will not work with `object`

It needs `dynamic` since `object` does not contain a definition for `Cost`, you would need to cast the object as either `Obj1` or `Obj2`. This leads to code duplication. It would be great if we could just cast as `T` but C# does not allow that.

```
public static void Foo<T>(object obj)
{
    if (!(obj is T)) 
    {
        var message = 
            string.Format("Expecting type of <{0}>.", typeof(T).Name);
        throw new System.ArgumentException(message);
    }

    // Compiler: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Cost'
    // obj.Cost = "11.99"; 

    if(obj is Obj1)
    {
        (obj as Obj1).Cost = "11.99"; 
    }
    else if(obj is Obj2)
    {
        (obj as Obj2).Cost = "11.99"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Though none of the approaches are ideal and result in a lot of housekeeping code and probably future maintenance issues, this solution is probably the least intrusive.

Comment: consider replacing the 

`if(a is T) { (a as T).myMethod() ;}` construct with 

`var t = a as T; if(t i!= null) { t.myMethod(); }`.

That makes one less convertion (`is` pretty much the same as `as` + `!= null`)


A tiny optimization, but an optimization nonetheless

Answer (score 5):

You can create an interface, and two proxy classes that implement it by forwarding calls to Obj1 and Obj2.

```
interface IObj {
   int calcCostObj1();
   ...
}

class Obj1Wrapper: IObj {
   Obj1 obj;

   int calcCostObj1() {
       return obj1.calcCostObj1();
   }
}
```

If you use Resharper, you can generate those proxy classes with "delegating members" refactoring

Answer (score 1):

As alex's answer, you should wrap your objects in a thin wrapper exposing the common members. But you can do even better to make your code transparent, by having your wrappers inherit from a common abstract class instead of a an interface. That way you can have implicit converters from `Obj1` and `Obj2` to it.

```
abstract class BaseObj
{
    public abstract double Cost { get; set; };
    public abstract double Rate{ get; set; }
    //...
}

class Obj1Wrapper : BaseObj
{
    private Obj1 _obj;

    public Obj1Wrapper(Obj1 obj)
    {
        this._obj = obj;
    }

    public override double Cost
    {
        get
        {
            return this._obj.Cost;
        }
        set
        {
            this._obj.Cost = value;
        }
     };

    public override double Rate
    {
        get
        {
            return this._obj.Rate;
        }
        set
        {
            this._obj.Rate= value;
        }
     };

     //...

    public static implicit operator BaseObj(Obj1 obj)
    {
        return new Obj1Wrapper(obj); 
    }
}

class Obj2Wrapper : BaseObj
{
    private Obj2 _obj;

    public Obj2Wrapper(Obj2 obj)
    {
        this._obj = obj;
    }

    public override double Cost
    {
        get
        {
            return this._obj.Cost;
        }
        set
        {
            this._obj.Cost = value;
        }
     };

    public override double Rate
    {
        get
        {
            return this._obj.Rate;
        }
        set
        {
            this._obj.Rate= value;
        }
     };

     //...

        public static implicit operator BaseObj(Obj2 obj)
    {
        return new Obj2Wrapper(obj); 
    }
}
```

Now you can use indifferently an `Obj1` or an `Obj2` as an argument in any method that are expecting a `BaseObj`.